# Show List in Grid Style C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a KPI Table that I need to display in a Block View type of thing...  I want the block view to be 3 columns wide... So if a client configured 8 KPI's... the first 3 show on Row 1, the next 3 on Row 2 and the remainder 2 on Row 3.

I have configured my KPI selection in a view.  So I want to render the view in this block style configuration.  My view rendering is working, just need pointers for the grid style setup

[image]

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap for your razor views?  If so, it's easy to use `<div class="col-md4">` for each KPI.and it should automatically wrap after the 3rd one.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, that worked like a charm!!!! You legend!

Answer (score 0):

Neil's response worked, Bootstrap grid

> Are you using Bootstrap for your razor views? If so, it's easy to use  for each KPI.and it should automatically wrap after the 3rd one

Answer (score -1):

You should look at UniformGrid ...

```
<UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3">
    <TextBlock Text="A1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="B1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="C1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="A2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="B2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="C2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="A3"/>
    <TextBlock Text="B3"/>
</UniformGrid>
```